# How do you use the context of a problem to determine what your error values mean in linear regression?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, mathematical-modeling, regression-analysis

I have been told that you must consider the context of a problem in order to determine what your error metrics are telling you.

**Question:**

What thought process would you go through to determine how good these numbers are in the exact context of this [data-set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data)?

**Context:**

I have created a linear regression model of two variables of the Iris data-set. The independent variable is "Petal Length" and the dependent variable is "Sepal Length". The error metrics have been calculated:

- **Average Sepal Length:** 5.843333
- **R-squared:**   0.703197
- **Mean Absolute Error:** 0.313679
- **Mean Squared Error:**  0.150961
- **Root Mean Squared Error:** 0.388537
- **Mean Error:** -0.88352

**Some answers I am not looking for:**

I am comfortable with the math behind some of the error metrics of linear regression, and I'm comfortable with what they represent in a big picture sort of way. For example, mean squared error is going to penalize large outliers by squaring the error. I realize that Mean Absolute Error does not do that. I also realize that Mean Absolute Error doesn't tell us which way our model is biased because it only counts magnitude, not direction. I know $R^2$ tells us how much better our model is than just predicting the average value. So these sorts of things are pretty clear and won't answer my question.

**Types of answers I am looking for:**

Based on $R^2$ it looks like my model is at least slightly better than just predicting the average. But how much better. What is the scale here?

I see that my model tends to under-estimate by 0.88 centimeters. That's about 20% of the average value, so that seems pretty bad to me. Is it really?

The mean squared is 2.5% of the average. What does that mean to me (I've seen this calculation done in example problems with no explanation of why)?

Comment: Mean error (as I understand it) should be zero.

Comment: Hi @tomi, Yes, ideally mean error would be zero. That would mean I am neither under or overestimating on average. I'll add a link to the data since it is 150 rows...

Comment: Hi @rocksNwaves. What method have you used to find your regression line?

Comment: @tomi I'm splitting the data into a training set and a test set. The training data is a random selection of 80% of the total data. I'm then running the training data through scikit-learn's LinearRegression object to obtain my regression coefficients. I have linked the data in the original question, and you can follow along my jupyter notebook here: https://github.com/wcneill/data-science-at-home/blob/master/jupyter_practice/linear_regression_02.ipynb and

Comment: @tomi and I just verified that scikit-learn uses ordinary least squares to calculate the regression parameters.